# How to fetch the items selected from a multiple choice list view?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to collect the list of students present in a class. The following attendanceactivity class is to take the attendance of students
this activity shows the list of roll nos of students.

**AttendanceActivity.class**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attendancelist);

    try {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                new ArrayList()));

        new AddStringTask().execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
    public void submit(View v){
    ArrayList<String> presentRoll = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    int len = getListAdapter().getCount();
    SparseBooleanArray checked = l.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (checked.get(i)) {
            presentRoll.add(object)

        }
}
```

what is the best method to write inside submit button to collect the student roll no. from the listview?

Answer (score 0):

```
Listview list;

final SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
//cast the list
//set the adapter...
....

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (!mSelectedItemsIds.get(position)) {
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                 presentRoll.add(list.getItemAtPosition(position)

            } else {
                 list.setItemChecked(position, false);
                mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
                presentRoll.remove(position)
            }


        }
    });
```

hope it help!

Comment: sry i am a beginner so can you tell me how to cast the list and set adapter? Thank you for your time..:)

Comment: ha my to use that word. just replace my listview with your  and implement setOnItemClickListener as above. i mean by cast to create a normal listView list like you did with the previous but since you already created one its irrelevant  ;) my bad